# How to do inline assembler on c++?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, visual-studio-2013

im trying to create a .wav player on c++ using assembler for an assignment, i found this tutorial on how to turn the speakers on and off: http://fly.srk.fer.hr/GDM/articles/sndmus/speaker1.html

but when i try to do it on c++ using "__asm{}" i get some errors... this is my code:

```
int main(){
    __asm{
        OUT 43h, B6h
        OUT 42h, 54
        OUT 42h, 124
        VALUE = IN(61h)
        VALUE = VALUE OR 3  
        OUT 61h, VALUE
    }
}
```

when i try to run it i get some errors like:

```
error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode';found 'constant'    
error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode';dounf 'bad token'
```

what am i doing wrong?

im using Visual Studio 2013

Thanks

Comment: According to your link, that isn't assembler for any particular CPU.  It's pseudocode.

Comment: I think the assignment is to write a player in assembly from scratch, not in C++ with inline assembly. That said, the mentioned tutorial is pointless - it's about direct hardware access, that will never work in Windows.

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that you'd get a DOS executable out of Visual Studio 2013 (though I'm not going to rule out the possibility). Reading and writing ports directly in a Windows executable is probably going to fail.

Comment: i just need the "play", "pause", "stop", "next song" and "previous song" functions in assembly code, the rest i will do it in c++, i'll make an interface too and all, but those specific functions must be in assembly code, like turning on the speaker and calculating the song duration but i have no idea on how to start